# How do I make my custom xampp domain name public?

Tags: http, xampp

I have created my own domain through hosts and xampp httpd. Now I was wondering how I make it accessible through the web(for other users)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase a domain through a registrar if you want it to be publicly accessible.

Once you've bought the domain, you setup DNS records to point it to your IP address.  This can usually be done through the registrar or you could use another DNS service.